# Very slow (1 second) connections

Tags: mysql, connection, 64-bit, myisam, mysql-5.6

I'm running MySQL 5.6 (64-bit) on Windows 7.  I'm testing a DB recently upgraded from MySQL 5.0 on 32-bit Windows 7.  (I also copied my.ini, with a few changes)

I'm finding that it takes a very long time to establish a connection (on the order of 1 second).  As an example, I created a very simple SQL script:

```
select 1 as n;
```

I then ran this in a batch file 10 times which took 10 seconds to complete:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -D myschema 0< myscript.sql
```

(Yes, there is no password here, this is a test DB listening only to 127.0.0.1)

Anyone have an idea why this is so very slow? (See my.ini below)

```
[client]
port=3306
[mysql]
default-character-set=latin1
[mysqld]
port=3306
bind-address=127.0.0.1
basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/mysql-5.6.10-winx64/"
datadir=C:/DATA
character-set-server=latin1
default-storage-engine=myisam
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
max_connections=100
query_cache_size=0
table_open_cache=256
tmp_table_size=18M
thread_cache_size=8
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=35M
key_buffer_size=25M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
sort_buffer_size=256K
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=47M
innodb_log_file_size=24M
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
log-bin=c:/data/mysql/binarylog
max_binlog_size=1024M
enable-named-pipe
slow_query_log=
expire_logs_days=90
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doh!  Looks like this is a dupe.  See:

[Why is connecting to MySQL server so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292856/why-connect-to-mysql-is-so-slow)

https://serverfault.com/questions/408550/connecting-to-mysql-from-php-is-extremely-slow

I've got IPv6 enabled on the 64-bit machine and not the 32-bit machine.  When I connect with the following alternate string, things are much quicker:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -D myschema 0< myscript.sql
```

Still not sure why this is happening, but at least there's a workaround!  Alas poor `localhost` I knew him well.

**EDIT:** The following change to my.ini allows use of `localhost` in scripts and connection strings:

```
bind-address=::1
```

Note: Binding to `::ffff:127.0.0.1` or `localhost` didn't seem to help.  I read about binding both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses to MySQL server so all 3 connection strings would work (e.g. `-h ::1`, `-h 127.0.0.1`, `-h localhost`).  However, I was only able to get one or two of those client strings to work at a time.

**EDIT2:** Binding in the following way:

```
bind-address=*
```

Completely resolves this issue and both IPv4 and IPv6 clients can connect.  The only drawback being that remote connections are now allowed.  I haven't found a way to use TCP with `localhost` restrictions and bind to both `127.0.0.1` **and** `::1`.

Comment: At first I thought this didn't apply to my case - connecting to MySQL server on a different machine in my local network. Found that it does! I suggest the answer be amended to describe the general case, not simply localhost / 127.0.0.1... i.e. ANY server node referenced by name vs IPv4 address.

Comment: @rObjects I agree that's great information, but not sure I can squeeze it in here.  Perhaps a stack overflow wiki entry would be better, which you or I can link from here.